# How to concatenate two dynamic char arrays?

Tags: c++

I have two char arrays defined like this:
`char* str = new char[size];`
How can I concatenate these two without creating an additional array?
I wrote the code below but it doesn't work:

```cpp
void append(char* str1, int size1, char* str2, int size2) {
    char* temp = str1;
    str1 = new char[size1+size2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        *(str1+i) = *(temp+i);
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = size1; i < size1+size2; i++) {
        *(str1+i) = *(str2+j);
        j++;
    }

    delete[] temp;
}
```

I forgot to mention that this is a homework and I MUST do it this way despite the fact that `std::string` and etc. exist. :(

Comment: ***How can I concatenate these two without creating an additional array?*** You can't. unless the destination array was already allocated as the size of both arrays.

Comment: you cannot concatenate them without creating another array. YOu have one array of size `size1` and a second one of size `size2` but the result is of size `size1 + size2`, that doesnt fit in either of the two, only in a another bigger array

Comment: ***"I have two char arrays defined like this: `char* str = new char[size];"`*** -- Why? [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) exists. (As does [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), for that matter. And if you *have* to dynamically allocate memory of your own, have a look at [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) as well. Pointers, arrays, and `new` are a code smell -- someone has gotten stuck halfway between C and C++. Go the whole way!

Comment: First of all you need to make sure that the destination array is large enough to hold the contents from both arrays, If there's no such guarantee then you don't really have any choice but to allocate a new array big enough.

Comment: @Parsa The code does not make a sense. For starters it is unclear whether the passed arrays contain strings. Also the function has no effect except it deletes memory allocated to the first array.

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` ? It can be as simple as `std::string(str1) + std::string(str2)` and you are done

Comment: the argument str1, in the caller function, still points to the original memory, the one you deleted deleting temp. You could return the new value of the newly allocated memory, and use it. But far better you use strings.

Comment: On another note, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter, array indexing syntax, is usually easier to read and understand. And less to write.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? Concatenating without concatenating isnt something one needs to do because its not possible ;)

Comment: @Sigi mentioned a very large bug in this code. You pass the str1 pointer by value. Meaning the code operates on a copy of `str1` and the function that calls it will not see the reallocation. This will be undefined behavior. Please reread your book on the difference between pass by value and pass by reference. You need pass by reference for the first argument leave the rest alone.

Comment: IMO, it's nonsense like this trying to get new programmers to do stuff like concatenation *the hard, error-prone* way is the reason why new programmers drop C++ and go to Python or some other language.  `std::string str1 = "whatever"; std::string s2 = " else"; std::string str3 = str1 + str2;`  Took all of 10 seconds to type that in.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Unfortunately many instructors insist on teaching students the way they learned it themselves: Hard C first, then discovering how easy C++ can be in comparison.  Losing most of their students somewhere along the way because C++ really seems to be the *only* language thus burdened by its ancestry. C++ *really* benefits from being taught top-down. Leave the char arrays and naked pointers for the advanced course, when you learn how to read the old crap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of my code was not passing the `str1` pointer by reference. 
Here is the corrected code:

```cpp
void append(char*& str1, int size1, char* str2, int size2) {
    char* temp = str1;
    str1 = new char[size1+size2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        *(str1+i) = *(temp+i);
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = size1; i < size1+size2; i++) {
        *(str1+i) = *(str2+j);
        j++;
    }

    delete[] temp;
}
```

Comment: no! Your problem is that you are learning C++ from bad source which mixes C idioms with C++ idioms whats ends with very bad code (which is neither good C or C++) and you learn bad practices. Please read carefully comments under question.

Comment: I know there are definitely better ways to do this but maybe I should mention that this is just a (stupid) homework and we're supposed to do it this way. I don't know why but... :)

Comment: But you just created an additional array `str1 = new char[size1+size2];` Besides, this is not a way to learn C++, if you want 2 strings, just use 2 `std::string`. These kind of exercises are worthless.

Comment: @Parsa -- Your code will fail miserably if `str1` was not allocated with `new[]` before the call.  For example: `char ch[1000]; append(ch, ...);` -- Your `append` function should not assume anything about where `str1` comes from.  It should simply take what comes in, and if the caller "forgot" to size `str1` with enough space, so be it.  Let them suffer.  So the code you wrote has so many flaws, it's a disservice if what you wrote in the answer is accepted by your teacher -- it is a disservice to you and your fellow students to believe what they are presenting is sound, good code.

Comment: Also, the size of your new string is probably incorrect. If you are dealing with null-terminated strings, then that size is `size1+slze2+1`, since you need to allocate not only enough space for the characters in the original strings, but the null terminator as well.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks. I did allocate it before calling it. I get the size from user and allocate it with the given size and reallocate it in the function like that.

Comment: @Parsa [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ece83eb58b9a73a).  The point is that I can take your answer, and make it not work, without changing a single line of the answer you posted.  The reason is not that the space is not sufficient, the reason is that you are issuing a `delete[]` call on something not allocated with `new[]`.  What if your teacher did a test like the code I posted at the link?  Or better yet, go to the teacher and see what they have to say, because the code is definitely flawed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I allocated str1 with new in `main`
`char* str1 = new char[size1];`
And in the function, I'm assigning its value to temp. Would that still be a problem?

Comment: @Parsa No, that is not a problem, but how do you know this is what the teacher who will test your program will do?  Maybe they will write the code I wrote, and give you a failing grade (or a poor grade) because your function cannot work under "normal" conditions.  A user program shouldn't be forced to use `new char[]` just to get a utility function to work properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right. So how can I fix it? Should I delete `delete[] temp`?

Comment: Unless your teacher specifically says otherwise, I would recommend not even trying to overwrite the input strings and just return a pointer to the new string that you allocated. (The burden would be on the user of your function to `delete[]` the string that you returned.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate if the result size of memory wasn't already allocated somewhere.
But you shouldn't be struggling yourself with staff like that when you are in C++,
you just have to do this:

```
string s1 = "some string one";
string s2 = "some string two";
s1 += s2; // or s1 = s1 + s2; appended, no need for loop and pointer copying.
```